# IndexError: list index out of range in Python with OpenCV and FaceRecognition

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import face_recognition
import os

path = 'Images'
images = []
classNames = []
myList = os.listdir(path)
print(myList)
for cl in myList:
    curImg = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cl}')
    images.append(curImg)
    classNames.append(os.path.splitext(cl)[0])
print(classNames)

def findEncodings(images):
    encodeList = []
    for img in images:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
        encodeList.append(encode)
    return encodeList

encodeListKnown = findEncodings(images)
print(len(encodeListKnown))
```

i really dont see my error here right now...
The console prints me ->

C:\Users\davut\PycharmProjects\QRCodeOpenCV\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/davut/PycharmProjects/QRCodeOpenCV/AttendanceProject.py
['Armagan.jpeg', 'Bill-Gates.jpg', 'Elon-Musk.jpg', 'Elon-Test.jpg', 'Gizem (1).jpeg', 'Muenster.jpg', 'Oezi.jpeg', 'Sude.jpeg']
['Armagan', 'Bill-Gates', 'Elon-Musk', 'Elon-Test', 'Gizem (1)', 'Muenster', 'Oezi', 'Sude']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/davut/PycharmProjects/QRCodeOpenCV/AttendanceProject.py", line 25, in 
encodeListKnown = findEncodings(images)
File "C:/Users/davut/PycharmProjects/QRCodeOpenCV/AttendanceProject.py", line 21, in findEncodings
encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: but these are test images on which faces are clearly to be found... 
In another project I use the same method and it works (but without a loop)

Answer (score 0):

alright the solution is, dont use a test photo without an face when using face_recognition ...